# looking for a vector (x) that yields unique dot products with any positive vector (a) in natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I'm looking for a natural (positive whole numbers) vector (x) that yields unique dot products with any natural vector (a), i.e. $ \bar x $ such that $ \bar a \bullet \bar x = S $ , where $S$ is unique for all $ \bar a $
Or in other words $\sum a_i x_i = S $ with unique $S$ for all $a_i$
where $ a_i, x_i \in \mathbb{N} $ (natural numbers).
Is it even possible to get such a sequence (vector)?
Thanks in advance.

A private case might be: $ax+by=c$ are there $(x,y)$ such that for all $(a,b)$ $ c$ is unique?

Comment: What's a positive vector?

Comment: This is not clear. What field are you working over?  Please define "positive vector".  If you just mean $\mathbb R$ and  "all components are $>0$" then it is not possible: If $x$ has a zero component then it is clearly not possible, otherwise if, say, $x_1,x_2>0$ then $(2x_2,x_1,1,1,\cdots) \cdot \vec x=(x_2,2x_1,1,1,\cdots)\cdot \vec x$ and so on.

Comment: yes, I forgot to add that all values  $ a_i, x_i $ are natural numbers (updated question)

Comment: Well, then my argument shows that it can not be done.

Comment: @lulu, can you please explain why there is no such finite vector x?

Comment: Given that all the $x_i$ are $>0$ the argument I gave is complete.

Comment: Consider $(ab,ab)$ and $(ab-b,ab+a)$.  When substituted for $x$ and $y$ in $ax+by$, you get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such sequence under the stated conditions. 
cotra-example by lulu (from comments to the original question):

$(2x_2,x_1,1,1,...)\bullet x = (x_2,2x_1,1,1,...)\bullet x$

Thanks lulu!